# How do I extend a ViewModel in Java, but override its Handlebars template entirely?

Tags: java, mvvm, handlebars.java

I have not seen the solution to this in: https://handlebarsjs.com/ or https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java

1. To override a template I need to:

```
{{#block "newFile" override="oldFile.hbs"}}
```

2. I also know that I can override elements while not losing the rest of the material by:

```
        {{#element "oldElement" noWith=true}}
```

3. But how do I override the entire page? I want to save time by extending a ViewModel based on another ViewModel, rather than creating a new ViewModel directly based on the original Model, but I want a similar ViewModel with a different View.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple:

Put this as a container around every inherited View you do not want:

```
{{#unless newViewModel}}

{{/unless}}
```

where newViewModel is a boolean set to true in your new ViewModel.

Then you can extend the ViewModel without extending its View.